# Spring Boot +CrudRepository + RestAPI +MySSQL - custom query is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, crud-repository

I am trying to create my first Spring Boot +CrudRepository + RestAPI +MySSQL. after initial hiccups, it's inserting and fetching records from the database. However when I send a custom query, it's not working. I do not get any exception however in Postman I am getting 404 not found status.

Here is my entity class

```
package com.it.skill.movies;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @Column(name="mno")
    private Integer mno;
    @Column(name="mname")
    private String mname;
    @Column(name="rating")
    private Integer rating;
    @Column(name="genre")
    private String genre;
    
    public Movie() {}

    
    
    public Movie(Integer mno, String mname, Integer rating, String genre) {
        super();
        this.mno = mno;
        this.mname = mname;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.genre = genre;
    }



    public Integer getMno() {
        return mno;
    }

    public void setMno(Integer mno) {
        this.mno = mno;
    }

    public String getMname() {
        return mname;
    }

    public void setMname(String mname) {
        this.mname = mname;
    }

    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(Integer rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [mno=" + mno + ", mname=" + mname + ", rating=" + rating + ", genre=" + genre + "]";
    }
}
```

Repository interface: this is where I wrote my query. is there an alternative to this as its a very simple query?

```
package com.it.skill.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.it.skill.movies.Movie;

@Repository 
public interface IMovieRepo extends CrudRepository<Movie, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m where m.genre=?1")
    public List<Movie> findByGenre(String genre);   
}
```

Service class

```
package com.it.skill.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.it.skill.movies.Movie;
import com.it.skill.repo.IMovieRepo;

@Service
public class IMovieService {

    @Autowired
    private IMovieRepo movieRepository;

        
    public Integer addMovie(Movie movie)
    {
        //Movie movie = new Movie();
        movieRepository.save(movie);
        return movie.getMno();
        
    }
    public List<Integer> addMovies(List<Movie> lstMovie)
    {
        //Movie movie = new Movie();
        List<Integer> lstRating = new ArrayList();
        
        for(Movie movie : lstMovie)
        {
            movieRepository.save(movie);
            lstRating.add(movie.getMno());
        }
        return lstRating;
        
    }
    public List<Movie> getAllMovies()
    {
        
        List<Movie> lstMovie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        movieRepository.findAll().forEach(e->lstMovie.add(e));
        return lstMovie;
    }
    public List<Movie> findMoviesByGenre(String genre)
    {
        
        List<Movie> lstMovie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        movieRepository.findByGenre(genre);
        return lstMovie;
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
package com.it.skill.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.it.skill.movies.Movie;
import com.it.skill.service.IMovieService;

@RestController
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private IMovieService movieService;
    
    //add single project
    @PostMapping(path = "/movie/add/", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> addMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        Integer iRating =  movieService.addMovie(movie);
        if(iRating!=null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Movie saved with rating: " +iRating, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Movie not saved", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    @PostMapping(path = "/movies/add/", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Integer>> addMovies(@RequestBody List<Movie> lsMovie) {
        List<Integer> lsRating =  movieService.addMovies(lsMovie);
        if(!lsRating.isEmpty())
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Integer>>(lsRating, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Integer>>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/movies/", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getAllMovies() {
        List<Movie> lsMovies =  movieService.getAllMovies();
        if(!lsMovies.isEmpty())
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(lsMovies, HttpStatus.FOUND);
        }
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    @GetMapping(path = "/movies/bygenre/{genre}", produces = { "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> getMoviesByGenre(@PathVariable("genre") String genre) {
        List<Movie> lsMovies =  movieService.findMoviesByGenre(genre);
        if(!lsMovies.isEmpty())
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(lsMovies, HttpStatus.FOUND);
        }
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

following are application properties

```
spring.application.name=Restful-App-Movies
server.servlet.context-path=/Restful-App-Movies
server.port=8082
## MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Asand9876@
```

When I use GET method in the postman using http://localhost:8082/Restful-App-Movies/movies/bygenre/"Horror" this link it throws 404 not found error.

why this below method in CrudRepository interface doesn't work as expected?
@Query("SELECT m FROM Movie m where m.genre=?1")
public List findByGenre(String genre);

Comment: http://localhost:8082/Restful-App-Movies/movies/bygenre/Horror  try without quotation

Comment: No. It did not work. same status

Comment: So if the list is empty then you are returning HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND which is basically 404. So maybe check your DB if it's having movies with the "Horror" genre. And also you are supposed to send a 404 when the URL is not found. Send some other exception saying it doesn't have movies with that genre name.

Comment: I have records matching those criteria in the database. I will make changes for the error. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Transactional annotation above addMovies() functions

Comment: No. It did not work. but why AddMovies? its working perfectly fine.

Comment: Spring should have a transactional boundary to persist the entity database.

Comment: I also see, `addMovie()` which does save as well. You have add `@Transactional` as well or you can annotate the class IMovieService as `@Transactional`

Comment: ok. I read about Transactional just now. makes sense. I annotated IMovieService as Transactional. However, it still does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove double quotes from request in order to get it working.
Correct syntax should be:

```
http://localhost:8082/Restful-App-Movies/movies/bygenre/Horror
```

Comment: thank you. yes, I did remove quotes and executed them. still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I made mistake in my service class. I declared the list object but did not return the list. When I updated my service method , it worked like charm. here is the updated method.

```
public List<Movie> findMoviesByGenre(String genre)
    {
        
        List<Movie> lstMovie = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        lstMovie = movieRepository.findByGenre(genre);
        return lstMovie;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestMapping` above `@RestController` annotation. So it becomes

```java
@RequestMapping
@RestController
public class MovieController {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't need super() in your Movie constructor
2. below is much less noisy - easier to read

```
    public List<Movie> findMoviesByGenre(String genre) {
        return movieRepository.findByGenre(genre);
    }
```